# Nuxt3 Error Handling showError works but throw createError doesn't

Tags: nuxtjs3

I am trying to use Nuxt3 error handling.

I have a page, say /posts/1 that wants to retrieve data from an API. I want a 404 to return if the API returns 404.

If I follow the Nuxt3 docs it says do this

```
const route = useRoute()
const { data } = await useFetch(`/api/posts/1`)

if (!data.value) {
  throw createError({
    statusCode: 404,
    statusMessage: 'Page Not Found'
  })
}
```

However, the throw createError just errors out with a blank page.

If I do,

```
 showError({
    statusCode: 404,
    statusMessage: "Post not found",
  });
```

This works and it displays default error.vue page.

I also want to know how to use the NuxtErrorBoundary as I would like to render the layout but not content, i.e. I don't want a full-page error.